# Strange RoundTo function behavior in two different computers

Tags: delphi, rounding

The problem is simple and strange!
I wrote a program in Delphi and used roundto function. In one computer 1.5 is rounded to 2 and in another computer it is rounded to 1.
How could this happen?

P.S: Code------> Roundto(1.5, 0)

P.S 2: It seems more information is needed so I post more exact detail. I wrote a program. They entered two number: a=7231.76 b=3556.71
Now they can enter a third number c if c >= a - b but the exact formation in my code is

```
`roundto(c, -1) >= roundto(a, -1) - roundto(b, -1)`
`roundto(a, -1) = 7231.8`
`roundto(b, -1) = 3556.7`
```

so

```
`roundto(a, -1) - roundto(b, -1) = 3675.1`
```

they entered

```
`c = 3675.05`
```

I traced the program. In one computer it says `round(c, -1) = 3675.1` and in another computer it says `round(c, -1) = 3675.0`

Comment: We would like to see that strange code too

Comment: @Mitch Wheat I posted it. It is in PS and PS2.

Comment: In order to investigate issues like this you need to learn to be precise and scientific. The inability to post the exact code you use, the inability to specify delphi version, these are your fundamental problems. You must learn to be more precise.

Comment: It is important for you as a software developer to learn than nothing is simple as it seems when you deal with floating point numbers. The rounded or truncated representations that you see on the screen are but the tip of the binary iceberg. read this: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would say you encountered the "banker's rounding" problem, and you posted the wrong data :-)
Delphi RoundTo implements the banker's rounding: Odd numbers that end in .5 are rounded upwards, that's the traditional behavior, but... Even numbers that end in .5 are rounded downwards!
So 1.5 is rounded to 2.0, but 2.5 is rounded to 2.0 (link to a reference of [RoundTo](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Math.RoundTo))

Second possibility: http://www.merlyn.demon.co.uk/pas-chop.htm#DRT there is a bug in certain versions of Delphi. Do you have the same version of Delphi in all the machines?

Third possibility: you are speaking of floating points! They aren't exact numbers! Adding and subtracting them creates a microworld of decimals normally invisible 0.1 + 0.2 != 0.3!! Perhaps what you see as .5 isn't exactly .5 but is .49999999 or .500000001. If you want to check it, step into the debugger and check if `c = 3675.05` (the logical expression) is true or false, if `round(c, -1) = 3675.1` is true or false and so on. If you want to explore the fp world, try this: http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~rkennedy/exact-float

Fourth possibility: the rounding of 3675.05 changes if you are using Single or Double. With Single it's 3675.1, with Double it's 3675 :-) Ah... the magical world of floats :-)

When you want to make mathematical tricks, please use the Currency type (it is a fixed point number and doesn't have these problems).

There is a last possibility, but it's quite improbable: the Intel CPU stores intermediate results of Double operations as 80 bits fp and then "round" them to 64 bits on output. Some compilers/languages introduce an optional optimization (that is activated on the run of the program if possible) to use the SSE2 opcodes present in some processors instead of the FPU of the processor. The SSE2 operate on 64 bits fp, so no upcasting to 80 bits and downcasting from 80 bits. This could cause what you are seeing. Read here [Differences between x87 FPU and SSE2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE2).

Comment: It was really interesting and thanks for this information. But my problem is different. I will edit my question for more information.

Comment: @Masoud I just wrote the expression in C#: (Math.Round(7231.76, 1) - Math.Round(3556.71, 1)).ToString("r") and the result is 3675.1000000000004 :-)

Comment: @xanstos I compiled it and sent the exe file to other computers. They have no version of delphi. and I entered same number in each program.

Comment: @Masoud And you haven't specified if you are using Single or Double

Comment: They are float numbers. I entered 7231.76 and 3556.71 and 3675.05 by myself in each computer. and they all use same exe file.

Comment: How could banker's rounding explain different results on different machines?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Because 5 times out of 10 what the OP writes in the question isn't what is really happening! So I extrapolated it, and in the end this "class" of problems is resolved by "knowledge of Banker's Rounding" or "knowledge of what a fp is". If you google around for Delphi RoundTo (or C# Math.Round) these are the "problems" the persons have.

Comment: I didn't understand. It wasn't solved. But it seems there is no answer. and xantos answer's were the best.

Comment: @Masoud Try declaring your variables as Currency and it will solve by itself.

Comment: as davidheffernan said it doesn't explain different results on different machine. Because they all run same exe file.

Comment: Yes. It is solved. But I can't understand why I had different answers on different machines.

Comment: @masoud there certainly will be an answer and we could help you find it. To do so you would need to give a complete program that gives different results on different machines.

Comment: @Masoud Because you haven't specified the version of the language you are using, you haven't specified the "type" of variables you are using (and no, floating point isn't enough), you initial post was "this line doesn't work help me". Persons here don't read the mind of posters.

Comment: @Masoud Added a fifth option... If what you wrote is really what happened, this would explain it.

Comment: +1 for `bankers rounding` I've been a chartered accountant for 10 years now, but I can tell you that nobody uses this brain dead rounding. We either just trucate because the decimals are immaterial or round properly.

Comment: @johan, this rounding technique is what is learned in school . It gives a correct average for a large number of random roundings.

Comment: @LU RD - not in my school it wasn't.  We were taught "0.5 rounds UP".  No if's and no but's.